# VBA : Me.Name function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet xlsm "My_workfile1", I would like to Save As this file like "My_final_workfile_1.xlsm".
I would like to hold all data in "My_final_workfile_1" and have the cells C4,C6,C7,C11,C12 in initial file "My_workfile1" empty after closing.

My code is:

```vb
Sub logFormState()
    Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C4") = ""
    Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C6") = ""
    Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C7") = ""
    Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C11") = ""
    Sheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ").Range("C12") = ""
End Sub

Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Me.Name = "My_workfile1" Then
        Call logFormState
    End If
End Sub
```

But `Me.Name` function doesn't work. I'm wondering if my code is correct.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The name will include the file extension (".xlsm")

Comment: I do not understand the meaning of `Me` in this context. The `BeforteClose` event will anyhow belong to the workbook where it exists...

Comment: @Rory Thank you, I added the xlsm but it doesn't work, the cells are not empty in my initial file :(

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you, but I can't undersatnd why my code doesn't work in initial file : the data is hold

Comment: Are you sure that `Workbook_BeforeClose` code event is inside `ThisWorkbook` module...? And what do you mean by "doesn't work in initial file"? Isn't it the one you want closing?

Comment: Did I wrongly understood that `Me.Name` is raising the error? If not, what error? If yes, you did not answer my previous question: Is `Workbook_BeforeClose `code event is inside `ThisWorkbook` module?

Comment: Maybe `My_workfile1` should be `My_workfile_1`. Are you sure that your worksheet name has a space at the end (`1 - Feuille de Suivi `)? Also, you have forgotten to save the file: `Me.Save` after `Call logFormState` or incorporate it in `logFormState`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 thank you, I added the Me.Save and I coorected My_workfile_1 : Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  If Me.Name = "My_workfile_1.xlsm" Then
        Call logFormState
        Me.Save
    End If
End Sub

Comment: @VBasic2008 I mean that I "Save As" the file My_workfile_1, after I open the file My_workfile_1 and I still have the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workbook `BeforeClose`

- [`Workbook.BeforeClose event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforeclose)
- [`Workbook.SaveCopyAs method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas)
- The first procedure is here only to help you to get your names right. It will show the names (and the folder path and the file path) in the `Immediate` window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DebugPrint()
    With ThisWorkbook
        Debug.Print "Workbook:"
        Debug.Print """" & .FullName & """"
        Debug.Print """" & .Path & """"
        Debug.Print """" & .Name & """"
        Debug.Print "Worksheet Names:"
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Debug.Print """" & ws.Name & """"
        Next ws
    End With
End Sub

Sub logFormState()
    ' Note that this worksheet name ends with a space!
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1 - Feuille de Suivi ")
        .Range("C4,C6,C7,C11,C12") = ""
        ' Either save here...
        .Parent.Save
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Me.Name = "My_workfile_1.xlsm" Then
        ' Change the path if necessary.
        Me.SaveCopyAs Me.Path & "\" & "My_final_workfile_1.xlsm"
        Call logFormState
        '... or save here:
        '.Save
    End If
End Sub
```